# Element addition

Tags: python

Good Morning,

I built two lists below:

```
Years = [1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985]
Amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400]

price = 0
for item in Years:
    i = 0
    while Years[i] <= item:
    price += Amount[i] 
    i += i
print(item,price)
```

How do I make this print so that it will only print years and corresponding total amount?

It should print:
1982  300

did i miss something here?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation on this? Also `i += i` will just be `0` always if `i` is 0. Try `i += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd do it using a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) structure, and by using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both lists simultaneously:

```
years = [1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985]
amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400]

results = {}
for y, a in zip(years,amount):
    if y in results:
        results[y] += a
    else:
        results[y] = a

for year, total in results.items():
    print(str(year) + ": " + str(total))
```

That way you can easily access each year and it's amount by going `results[year]` to get the corresponding amount.

Also I renamed `Years` and `Amounts` to `years` and `amounts` because it's convention to use lowercase first letters on variables in Python.

To avoid the test to see if a key is in the `results` dictionary (the if statement), you could also use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) structure:

```
import collections

years = [1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985]
amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400]

results = collections.defaultdict(int)
for y, a in zip(years,amount):
    results[y] += (a)

for year, total in results.items():
    print(str(year) + ": " + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index of the list you are iterating over.

```
for ind, item in enumerate(Years):
    print(item, sum(Amount[:ind+1]))
```

The [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function takes a list a returns its sum. To get the prices up to the current year, you can use [list splicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to access the relevant list items.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. Here I create a code that should be easier to understand

```
Years = [1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985]
Amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400]

price = 0
for i in range(len(Years)):
    print(str(Years[i]) + ' ' + str(Amount[i]))
```

This will give you the following output:

```
1982 100
1983 200
1984 300
1985 400
1982 100
1983 200
1984 300
1985 400
1982 100
1983 200
1984 300
1985 400
```

Comment: I want to sum up each element in the list Amount, corresponding to the Years List.  
For example:
    1982  300
    1983  600
    1984  900
    1985  1200

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **zip** function:

```
Years = [1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985]
Amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400]
for b in zip(Years, Amount):
    print(b[0], b[1])
```

An even more condensed (elegant?) way to use the **zip** function is:

```
for a,b in zip(Years, Amount):
    print(a, b)
```